# Ajax rendering "freezes" for a while when updating h:selectManyListbox with 10.000 items

Tags: ajax, jsf, mojarra

I am using Mojarra JSF (v2.2.10) with Spring (v3.2.5) for a small admin-console on a tomcat (also Twitter Bootstrap for styling). 
Basically there is a multiple select box which I can add new entries to via textbox and button. I can also remove entries by selecting them and clicking the remove button.

Here is the relevant code piece:

```
<h:form>
<h:outputLabel for="selectedEntries" value="Selected entries" />
<h:selectManyListbox id="selectedEntries" value="#{myBean.entriesToRemove}">
  <f:ajax/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selectedEntries}" />
</h:selectManyListbox>
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.addEntriesToSelection}" value="Add">
  <f:ajax render="selectedEntries entriesInput" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.removeEntriesFromSelection}">
  <f:ajax render="selectedEntries entriesInput" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputLabel for="entriesInput" value="Input" />
<h:inputTextarea id="entriesInput" value="#{myBean.entriesInput}">
  <f:ajax/>
</h:inputTextarea>
```

The fields "entriesToRemove" and "selectedEntries" are simple String Lists and the field "entriesInput" is a String.

Everything works just fine, but when the "selectedEntries" list grows to say 10.000 entries, I hit a performance problem: When I try to add a new entry into this overgrown list, the page freezes for about 30 seconds before it renders the updated list. The same goes for removing an entry. This freeze however does not occur in the method "addEntriesToSelection" but rather afterwards, when the backing bean fields are already updated. So I assume this has something to do with the rendering of the page.

Does anybody have a clue, how I could solve this problem? Is this maybe Mojarra- or JSF-specific?

Comment: Is the "freeze" server or client side? If client side, have you tried other clients? With 10.000 elements in HTML DOM and e.g. Internet Explorer as client, I'd not be surprised if it's just the client application itself.

Comment: Hi BalusC, thanks for the fast reply. How do I figure out whether it is client- or server-side? IE11 and Chrome v38 both behave the same way. In Firefox v18 the freeze seems to be only half es long.

Comment: Just debug/stopwatch the process in both sides.

Comment: I can't figure it out for sure, but it seems to be the server-side. When I debug the client-side, the jsf.js sends the ajax-request and only after those 30 seconds the "doUpdate" method is called.
On the server-side my method only takes 1-2 seconds, but I suppose it takes that long for rendering the response.

Comment: Okay...after debugging the jsf.js some more, I figured out what caused the freeze: It is when the newly generated html (with the 10.000 entries) is being set to the innerHTML of a parserElement. There the browser freezes, as it apparently can't handle that much data fast enough. Only question is, how can I fix this issue? I definetly need those 10.000 entries for my app (even if it might sound a bit extreme :-P).

Comment: OK, client side thus. Sorry, that's beyond control of JSF. You'd better introduce a search/autocomplete input instead of showing all those 10.000 items at once (which **IS** extreme, and not a bit!).

Comment: Thanks again! I suppose I will have to look into alternatives like the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a client side problem, not a server side problem. Some browsers, particularly MS Internet Explorer, are known to be laggy when updating the HTML DOM tree with an "insane" amount of new HTML elements. Certainly 10.000 listbox items is "insane". Google e.g. also doesn't show all those million potential matches at once when you open the search homepage. Instead, it shows an autocomplete-capable input field allowing you to find and filter the relevant data.

Consider turning that listbox into a search/autocomplete input field.